# "AttributeError: Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field" when trying to serialize a relation in my view

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to only return the one treatment related to the patient that is currently making the call.

I have the following models:
models.py

```py
class User(AbstractUser):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    street_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    street_number = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    post_code = models.IntegerField(null=True)

    clinic = models.ForeignKey("Clinic", on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

    is_patient = models.BooleanField()
    is_physio = models.BooleanField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email


class Patient(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    physio = models.ForeignKey("Physio", on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.pk


class Treatment(models.Model):
    physio = models.ForeignKey(Physio, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    patient = models.ForeignKey(
        Patient, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    clinic = models.ForeignKey(Clinic, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField()
    treatment_notes = models.TextField()
    date_created = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        # TODO add Patient ID
        treatment_str = f"Patient ({self.objects.patient}) - {str(self.date_created)}"
        return treatment_str
```

With the following serializer:
serializers.py

```py
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    physio = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(read_only=True)
    patient = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'email',
                  'password', 'is_patient', 'is_physio', 'patient', 'physio')


class PatientSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Patient
        fields = '__all__'

class TreatmentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    physio = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(read_only=True)
    patient = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = models.Treatment
        fields = '__all__'
        read_only_fields = ['date_created']
```

And I'm trying to make a call to the following view:
views.py

```py
class TreatmentPatientRetrieveView(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    serializer_class = TreatmentSerializer

    def get_object(self):
        patient = self.request.user.patient
        return Treatment.objects.filter(patient=patient)
```

Yet I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `is_active` on serializer `TreatmentSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on 
the `QuerySet` instance.
Original exception text was: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'is_active'.
```

I'm pretty new to DRF, but I've been trying to figure this out for days now and simply cannot. I have tried to read the documentation and other StackOverflow questions/answers many times, but have gotten nowhere. I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `get_object` method is returning a queryset instead of a model object. Change it to return a single object like this.

```py
Treatment.objects.get(patient=patient)
```

Comment: Solved! You are an absolute legend! Gosh, I feel dumb, but I've learned a lot from this. Thank you!